# Why does iteration on my list fail?

Tags: c++, linked-list

I'm currently working my way through the Stanford open CS106B, and I'm running into a problem on Assignment 3, Part B. I am given a struct Node as follows:

```
struct Node {
string name;   // my person's name
string killer; // who eliminated me
Node* next;    // ptr to next node
Node(string name, Node* next) {...}
};
```

I have to implement a class that makes a list of Nodes. I have the constructor working properly, but when I try to iterate through the list, my program crashes. My iteration code:

```
void AssassinsList::printGameRing() {
    Node* current;
    for(current = ring; current->next != NULL; current = current->next) {
        cout << endl << "  " << current->name << " is targeting " << current->next->name;
    }
    cout << endl << "  " << current->name << " is targeting " << ring->name << endl;
}
```

However, if I use a for-loop to loop the number of times I know I need to for a certain list length, it works. Help? The link to the assignment pdf: http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs106b/homework/3-tiles-assassins/spec.pdf

Thanks!

Comment: I somehow can't spot any error in the code you provided. You will have to show more code.

Comment: in your printGameRing you address "next" but in your struct (that you show) there is no such member, how do you expect us to help you if you don't show the relevant parts?

Comment: he checks before current->next!=NULL so current->next will be thee

Comment: Your question doesn't tell us anything about the crash itself.  I infer that it is an access violation based on the fact that you said a fixed iteration count works.  Are you initializing "next" to NULL when you create a Node?  It seems likely that your check "current->next != NULL" isn't working properly.

Comment: There really isn't more code to show because the rest is provided; I simply need to implement the class AssassinsList. I hate to send you to read an assignment description, but I think it explains the assignment better than I could.

Comment: I fixed the bad paste for the struct. You guys are fast...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am guessing that you don't initialize `* next` to `nullptr`.  So for all the links you setup between nodes it is fine, but the last object in the list points to garbage.

Sorry, `nullptr` is c++11.  If your compiler older then its just `NULL`.

Comment: Ah... You are correct, sir. I focus too much on the loop to notice that my first next pointer was set to target, but target wasn't set to null. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There's a chance that if `cur` is NULL or doesn't point to anything, you could be dereferencing a bad pointer and therefore crashing your program. The other option is that as woolstar pointed out, you don't have a terminating node in your list (that points to NULL.) Observe the following code:

```
Node* head = new Node{0};
Node* cur = head;
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
{
    cur->next = new Node{i};
    cur = cur->next;
}

// Set terminating node
cur->next = nullptr;

// We'll iterate until cur is null
// So if we access cur->next
// It won't result in undefined behavior
for (cur = head; cur != nullptr; cur = cur->next)
{
    std::cout << cur->value;
}

// cur should be nullptr now
if (!cur)
    std::cout << "end of list";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use 0. Yeah, it's not as cool as `nullptr`, but it's supported. Fixed constructor:

```
Node(string name_, Node* next_=0): name(name_), next(next_) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

The fact a fixed length loop works, but a NULL terminated loop doesnt work shows that its likely you have an invalid address in the last Node's next field.

I would expect your problem comes from either your Node constructor or your list code or the interplay between them.

Try setting next to `0`/`nullptr` in the Node constructor, that should help.

Alternatively, have your list set the next field to 0 when you add the first element to the list, or add any element to the end of the list.